Problema de migracion en alambic
Me generó este error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Scripts\alembic.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 636, in main
    CommandLine(prog=prog).main(argv=argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 626, in main
    self.run_cmd(cfg, options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 603, in run_cmd
    fn(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 236, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 586, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 95, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 113, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Acceso-Cristian\Desktop\Proyect_API\alembic\env.py", line 95, in <module>
    with context.begin_transaction():
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 8, in begin_transaction
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 1023, in begin_transaction
    return self.get_context().begin_transaction()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 1034, in get_context
    raise Exception("No context has been configured yet.")
Exception: No context has been configured yet.

¿Qué solución me recomienda para hacer una buena migración de una base datos en postgresql con alembic?
Seria una gran ayuda que alguien me ayudara con este problema.

Buenas por favor, agrega más detalles. Solamente el error no basta. Debes decir que estabas haciendo, que hiciste, y como se generó el error.
